# How can I grab comma delimited values that appear after a term I searched for?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, csv

Here's my code so far:

```
public void DeserialStream(string filePath)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string currentline;
            while ((currentline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (currentline.IndexOf("Count", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(currentline);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I was wondering how can I grab comma delimited values that appear after a term I searched for?

Like if I a csv that contained this info:

```
"Date","dd/mm/yyyy"
"ExpirationDate","dd/mm/yyyy"

"DataType","Count"
"Location","Unknown","Variable1","Variable2","Variable3"
"A(Loc3, Loc4)","Unknown","5656","787","42"
"A(Loc5, Loc6)","Unknown","25","878","921"

"DataType","Net"
"Location","Unknown","Variable1","Variable2","Variable3"
"A(Loc3, Loc4)","Unknown","5656","787","42"
"A(Loc5, Loc6)","Unknown","25","878","921"
```

But how would I grab the table of values after Count but before Net?

That is, only the data is brackets is what I want to parse:

```
"Date","dd/mm/yyyy"
    "ExpirationDate","dd/mm/yyyy"

    "DataType","Count"
   [ "Location","Unknown","Variable1","Variable2","Variable3"
    "A(Loc3, Loc4)","Unknown","5656","787","42"
    "A(Loc5, Loc6)","Unknown","25","878","921"]

    "DataType","Net"
    "Location","Unknown","Variable1","Variable2","Variable3"
    "A(Loc3, Loc4)","Unknown","5656","787","42"
    "A(Loc5, Loc6)","Unknown","25","878","921"
```

I was thinking maybe I should use a regular expression or is there an easier way using the method above?

Comment: You need to provide more information on how the CSV is formatted. If you want to use a regex you need to provide all possible patterns the regex has to find. Now, how do you want to capture the values in the comma delimited list? would a simple string[] produced from `Split()` work?

Comment: How would I customize Split() such that only the text that appears after Count is grabbed but before another similar field of text, in the example above before DateType, Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(path)
   .SkipWhile(l => l.IndexOf("\"Count\"", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1)
   .Skip(1) // skip the "Count"-line
   .TakeWhile(l => l.IndexOf("\"Net\"",   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1)
   .ToList();
```

Use `String.Split` to get a `string[]` for every line. In general i would use an [available CSV parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906841/csv-parser-reader-for-c) which handle edge cases and bad data instead of reinventing the wheel.

**Edit**: If you want to split the fields into a `List<string>` you should use a CSV parser as mentioned since your data already uses a quoting character, so commas wrapped in `"` should not be splitted.

However, here is another simple but efficient approach using a `StringBuilder`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitCSV(string csvString)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool quoted = false;

    foreach (char c in csvString)
    {
        if (quoted)
        {
            if (c == '"')
                quoted = false;
            else
                sb.Append(c);
        }
        else
        {
            if (c == '"')
            {
                quoted = true;
            }
            else if (c == ',')
            {
                yield return sb.ToString();
                sb.Length = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
    }

    if (quoted)
        throw new ArgumentException("csvString", "Unterminated quotation mark.");

    yield return sb.ToString();
}
```

( thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4150727/284240 )

Now you can use `SelectMany` in the query above to flatten out all tokens:

```
List<string> allTokens = File.ReadLines(path)
    .SkipWhile(l => l.IndexOf("\"Count\"", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1)
    .Skip(1) // skip the "Count"-line
    .TakeWhile(l => l.IndexOf("\"Net\"", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1)
    .SelectMany(l => SplitCSV(l.Trim()))
    .ToList();
```

Result:

```
Location, Unknown, Variable1, Variable2, Variable3, A(Loc3, Loc4), Unknown, 5656, 787, 42, A(Loc5, Loc6), Unknown, 25, 878, 921, ""
```

Comment: Hmm I think I might have to use split... since in this case, I am also getting System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] and a recursive script? it loops frequently (not sure why?)

Comment: @KalaJ: what is your desired result at all? _"grab the table of values after Count but before Net"_ is not really helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the recursive problem. I just want to make sure I'm adding the values of "Location","Unknown","Variable1","Variable2","Variable3"
    "A(Loc3, Loc4)","Unknown","5656","787","42"
    "A(Loc5, Loc6)","Unknown","25","878","921" into a list. Eventually this will go into one of my db tables.

Comment: @KalaJ: what are the "values" you want, a `List<string>` which contains entries like `Location` or `Unknown`  or even a `Dictionary<string, string>` where the key is `Location` and the value is `A(Loc3, Loc4)` (for example) ?

Comment: @KalaJ: i've edited my answer to show the list approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\"DataType\"\,\"(?:Count|Net)\"((?!\"DataType\").)*
```

This would match the DataType line all the way to the next DataType line.

Comment: That would work, the problem is I have a csv file that contains several DataTypes.... DataType A, B, C, D, E,.... and I just want info from DataType C to D. In the above example, I want to specify the Regex to include Count and Net since those are the only unique identifiers

Comment: Btw, I have another question, if I had the same CSV format above but with a 21X23 grid of data, would the regular expression change?

Comment: What's important with regular expressions is the format of the text. It doesn't matter if grid changes as long as the pattern the regex matches doesn't change. If it does I suggest you create a new question.

Comment: Btw, I have a small question, if I want to use the regular expression above, I would write something like this right:  var countRegex = new Regex("\"DataType\"\,\"(?:Count|Net)\"((?!\"DataType\").)*"); However, in my Visual Studio, it's telling me that the comma is unrecognized escape sequence? How do I fix that?

Comment: try putting a @ before your string: `var countRegex = new Regex(@"\"DataType\"\,\"(?:Count|Net)\"((?!\"DataType\").)*");`

Comment: Actually, it think it just had to do with not escaping the comma, so I removed \ from the comma and it works. However, when I parse my csv file, it only gives me "DataType", "Count" and "DataType", "Net" and not the information/table in-between them. Not sure why.

Comment: Use the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option. This would make "." match newline as well.

Comment: I will post a new question. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767254/regex-returns-terms-and-not-information-in-between-terms