# Regex returns terms and not information in between terms

Tags: c#, regex, csv

Here's my code:

```
public void DeserialStream(string filePath)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string currentline;
            Regex countRegex = new Regex("\"DataType\",\"(?:Count|Net)\"((?!\"DataType\").)*", RegexOptions.Singleline); 
            while ((currentline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                    foreach (Match match in countRegex.Matches(currentline))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(match.Value); 
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Here's my CSV:

```
"Date","dd/mm/yyyy"
"ExpirationDate","dd/mm/yyyy"

"DataType","Count"
"Location","Unknown","Variable1","Variable2","Variable3"
"A(Loc3, Loc4)","Unknown","5656","787","42"
"A(Loc5, Loc6)","Unknown","25","878","921"

"DataType","Net"
"Location","Unknown","Variable1","Variable2","Variable3"
"A(Loc3, Loc4)","Unknown","5656","787","42"
"A(Loc5, Loc6)","Unknown","25","878","921"
```

I want to return the data between "DataType", "Count" and "DataType", "Net" below. However, my compiler is returning the terms: "DataType", "Count" and "DataType", "Net" and not the data in between. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I grab comma delimited values that appear after a term I searched for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763992/how-can-i-grab-comma-delimited-values-that-appear-after-a-term-i-searched-for)

Comment: Are you trying to match the header rows, or the actual data rows below them?  Your Regex, I believe, will match the header row, not the data rows...

Comment: I am trying to match the actual data rows below Count but above Net. Not the headers...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the : from DataType:

Edit:
Try this Regex "\"DataType\",\"(?:Count|Net)\"((?:(?!\"DataType\").)*)"

Comment: Still same issue from above even though I removed : .

Comment: I think the regex you gave me is wrong. I don't want the headers, I want the data in between the headers.

Answer (score 0):

[This may be what you're looking for](http://regex101.com/r/aW4zA0), though you may need to adjust:

```
\"DataType\",\"(?:Count|Net)\"\n((((?<Location>\"[^\"]*\"),(?<Unknown>\"[^\"]*\"),(?<Var1>\"[^\"]*\"),(?<Var2>\"[^\"]*\"),(?<Var3>\"[^\"]*\"))\n)*)
```

- Keep in mind that it doesn't support correct CSV parsing (will not handle escaped `"` in the middle of value).
- Keep in mind that it doesn't allow for spaces between commas
- It assumes there is a blank line after data rows and before next header rows.
- Whatever else may be left out :) - adjust accordingly (i.e. it may have extra capture groups, so you may need to adjust for that). This is intended more to get you going than a perfect solution.

Comment: I have a question... since it Regex seems more painful than initially though, is there a way to grab that data I want besides RegEx?

Comment: Yes, by using any suitable CSV parser.  In fact, that would be a preferred way.  You can find SO post on it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642055/csv-parsing-options-with-net

Answer (score 0):

I think this pattern will do `\"DataType\",\"Count\"(.*?)\"DataType\",\"Net\"` w/ `s` option
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uQ6qL3)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Rubular, http://rubular.com/. Not sure why... How do I include s modifier in the regular expression above?

Comment: use this instead `"DataType","Count"([\s\S]*?)"DataType","Net"` [rubular Demo](http://rubular.com/r/KiaKYTbxeA)